# Views not saving after upgrading

Tags: 7, views, upgrading

I am upgrading my website from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7.  In the Views module, when I attempt to save a view I now get the following error:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
'human_name' in 'field list': UPDATE {views_view} SET
name=:db_update_placeholder_0, description=:db_update_placeholder_1,
tag=:db_update_placeholder_2, base_table=:db_update_placeholder_3,
human_name=:db_update_placeholder_4, core=:db_update_placeholder_5
WHERE (vid = :db_condition_placeholder_0) ; Array (
[:db_update_placeholder_0] => Last_update [:db_update_placeholder_1]
=> last update [:db_update_placeholder_2] => [:db_update_placeholder_3] => node [:db_update_placeholder_4] =>
[:db_update_placeholder_5] => 0 [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 11 )
in views_db_object->save_row() (line 2092 of
/home/yektafil/domains/dl.yektafile.info/public_html/sites/all/modules/views/includes/view.inc).
```

Does anyone know what's causing this?

Answer (score 1):

The message states that views is missing a database column (human_name) it is expecting to exist. New fields in core or contributed modules are often added by an update process.

It looks as if you need to run update.php, because it was not run after upgrading core or the views module itself. Alternatively, if you have drush enabled, you can run 'drush updb' from a shell.